# How to listen all of the available Laravel Model events inside Trait

Tags: php, laravel, events, model, traits

I have been using `Traits` for some of the repetitive functionalities such as Generating `guid` or logging some events. But now I need to do something more robust such as logging all of the user activities.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
public static function bootLoggable()
{
    static::creating(function ($model) {
        dd($model);
    });
}
```

Aside from the above one, I also would like to add all of the available model listeners, but for example, if I add the below one for instance

```
public static function bootLoggable()
{
    static::creating(function ($model) {
        dd($model);
    });

    static::updating(function ($model) {
        dd($model);
    });
}
```

it no longer seems to work, I tried to find some more information on the topic, but couldn't get too far. I'm clearly doing something against the working logic of these events.

Comment: Make sure your trait is still named `Loggable`. Also, what do you mean it no longer works? Non of the events work?

Comment: No, I mean `creating` event is still working, but the rest does not.

Comment: Of course the rest won't, because you are doing `dd()`, it kills execution of the script.

Comment: But they never run if do deletion for example.

Comment: swap `dd($model)` with `dump('creating')` and `dump('updating')`, then select random model from DB and update it (that means change some attributes and call `save()` to persist those changes). Then come back to us with the result.

Comment: Even tho I removed all of the other events and added `echo "hello"` it still doesn't work

Comment: show us the code you do to dispatch `updating` event. Maybe you are misunderstanding when it triggers. Update your question with more details.